# Why is Python so much slower than JavaScript? Could it ever catch up?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, performance

I am a PhD student, and I have been creating Python programs to handle massive scientific calculations.
Even after using optimal Computer Science algorithms, my scripts often take hours to complete.

I recently tried to implement some of the heavier functions in JavaScript to compare its performance, and it was 10x times faster right away.

This left me wondering why is JavaScript so much Faster than Python, if both are interpreted languages. Could Python could ever catch up with this performance? (Perhaps restricting a few minor operations, or adding optional declarations to improve speed).

PS. I have read that the performance improvements that I noticed in JavaScript are powered by advanced Google Chrome technology, so I guess my question could be rephrased as asking whether these technologies could also be applied to speed up standard Python.

Comment: Python has unbounded integers; that is, they are not implemented as native numbers on the platform but instead they're in software (at least to some extent). JavaScript numbers are native 64-bit floating point (unless you're using the relatively new "big int" type, which is essentially the same as Python's integers).

Comment: @Pointy thank for your answer. That is an interesting point, I guess that explains why Python is so slow for arithmetics lol. It would be great if Python allowed some simple options to catch up with JavaScript performance (at least partially).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here the reason for python to be slow is because, python runs c programme at its backend.
What I meant by it is that every variable/ object you create in python has an 'C' struct defined at its backend for find that variables size,datatype, and other three parameters. Hence, each time you run the python code it first runs that c code in backed and shows you result.
Hence, python is much slower compared to javascript or java.

Comment: Well the JavaScript and Java runtimes have to do basically the same thing.

Comment: @Shubham Ashtaputre Thanks for the feedback. Do you think there is something that Python could do so improve its performance? Like letting you define a variable as a simple "double" data type and run at the speed of light? I love Python, but I think its speed difference with other interpreted languages will have to be addressed some day.

Comment: @Pointy Javascript in Chrome and Firefox uses JIT sometimes

Comment: The explanation is misleading and confusing. There is no C code being run directly in the backend, unless you mean that the interpreter machine code is written in C (it is). But the interpreter of Javascript (i.e., the browser) is also written in C/C++. So the observation is meaningless. The real reason is how optimised various interpreters are. Browser engines are highly optimised pieces of software, while the standard interpreter of Python is not, focusing on correctness and other features. If you use Pypy (for JIT), or cython, you can get Python code to be very fast as well.